# How to enable app inspection tool bar in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to view the local database in android studio but I am unable to see the app inspection option in my android studio

MY android studio version:[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[Image of my android tool bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li0j7.jpg)

Comment: [Supposedly](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler), "App Inspection" is at `View > Tool Windows > App Inspection`. However, I am trying to debug network traffic and I don't have that menu item under `View > Tool Windows`.  Fortunately, I found network info through the menu item `View > Tool Windows > Profiler`.  Maybe you want `View > Tool Windows >  Database Inspector`?

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you find any solution?